# Cannot create emulator via Jenkins' Android Emulator Plugin

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation, jenkins-plugins

When Jenkins tries to generate my emulator, it errors out with:

```
tools/android create avd -f -a -c 256M -s 1080x1920 -n hudson_de-DE_480_1080x1920_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_x86 -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi x86
Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected target.
```

But `tools/android list targets` outputs

```
id: 6 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/x86
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong (though I would be surprised if a 1080x1920 emulator boots properly (but maybe API 23 works better)) — this is a bug, which I've filed as https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `--abi` parameter needs a fix, not the `--tag` parameter. The error is misleading:

```
$ tools/android create avd -f -a -c 256M -s 1080x1920 \
   -n hudson_de-DE_480_1080x1920_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_x86 \
   -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/x86
```

Comment: This didn't work for me... I had to change both the tag and the abi as follow: android create avd -f -a -c 256M -s 1080x1920 -n hudson_de-DE_480_1080x1920_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_x86 -t "android-23" --abi google_apis/x86_64

Comment: @FrançoisPOYER Actually I think you only have x86_64 images, therefor this fails for you. Also, if you haven't yet downloaded the image that includes the Google APIs, you most likely can only target plain "android-23".

Comment: No, I made sure to have ALL images (using sdk manager, I un-installed and re-installed my system-images for 23 API) before running the command, both x86 and 64 . Also both the "vanilla" android-23 and the Google APIs one. Only command that works for me is the one I gave...
I feel like Google may have changed package names / tag /ABI strategy again...